# How to derive the same function with different file path in two different singleton class or normal class?

Tags: c++

I have two different classes with same function uploadToFile() which take different file paths.

I have used the singleton class now and have different objects to access the function.

The code is as below.

Inventorylist.cpp

```
InventoryList* InventoryList::pInventoryList =NULL;
std::once_flag InventoryList::InventoryListInstanceFlag;

InventoryList* InventoryList::getInstance()
{
    std::call_once(InventoryListInstanceFlag, []{
        pInventoryList = new InventoryList();
        pInventoryList->runInternalThread=true;
        pthread_create(&pInventoryList->writer, NULL, (void* (*)(void*))&InventoryList::updateToFile, pInventoryList);
        }
    );
    return pInventoryList;
}

NodeList.cpp

NodeList* NodeList::pNodeList =NULL;
std::once_flag NodeList::NodeListInstanceFlag;

NodeList* NodeList::getInstance()
{
    std::call_once(NodeListInstanceFlag, []{
            pNodeList = new NodeList();
            pNodeList->runInternalThread=true;
            pthread_create(&pNodeList->writer, NULL, (void* (*)(void*))&NodeList::updateToFile, pNodeList);
            }
      );
    return pNodeList;
}

InventoryList::UpdateTofile()

void InventoryList::updateToFile()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if((pInventoryList->writeTImer.GetEnabled() && pInventoryList->writeTImer.IsDone()) ||
            pInventoryList->bailoutTimer.IsDone())
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> invlock(pInventoryList->mutex_NodeInvConf);
//#if _DEBUG_LOG
            FILE * pFile;
            std::string conff =  pInventoryList->NodeInvConfiguration.toStyledString();
//           LOG_G("inventory file data %s",conff.c_str());
            pFile = fopen (KV_FOLDER_LOCATION DIR_SEP KV_READABLE_INVENTORYLIST_FILE, "wb");
            fwrite (conff.c_str() , sizeof(char), conff.length(), pFile);
            fclose (pFile);
            sync();
//#endif
            FILE * pFile2;
            pFile2 = fopen (/*KV_FOLDER_LOCATION DIR_SEP KV_INVENTORYLIST_FILE*/SYS_INV_PATH , "wb");
            PrintJSONTree(pInventoryList->NodeInvConfiguration,0,pFile2);
            fclose (pFile2);
            sync();
            pInventoryList->writeTImer.SetEnabled(false);
            LOG_G("Inventory file updated");
            LOGS_INFO("Inventory file updated");
            MessageQueInterface::getInstance()->sendInventory(true);
            pInventoryList->bailoutTimer.Reset();
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

NodeList::updateToFile()

void NodeList::updateToFile()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(pNodeList->writeTImer.GetEnabled() && pNodeList->writeTImer.IsDone())
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> panellock(pNodeList->mutex_NodeInvConf);
//#if _DEBUG_LOG
            FILE * pFile;
            std::string conff =  pNodeList->NodeInvConfiguration.toStyledString();
            pFile = fopen (KV_FOLDER_LOCATION DIR_SEP KV_READABLE_NODELIST_FILE , "wb");
            fwrite (conff.c_str() , sizeof(char), conff.length(), pFile);
            fclose (pFile);
            sync();
//#endif
            FILE * pFile2;
            pFile2 = fopen (/*KV_FOLDER_LOCATION DIR_SEP KV_NODELIST_FILE*/SYS_PNL_PATH, "wb");
            PrintJSONTree(pNodeList->NodeInvConfiguration,0,pFile2);
            fclose (pFile2);
            sync();
            pNodeList->writeTImer.SetEnabled(false);
            LOG_G("Nodelist file updated");
            LOGS_INFO("Nodelist file updated");
            MessageQueInterface::getInstance()->sendInventory(false);

        }
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

I want to write these two different updateTofile in one base class and derive to two different class by passing the file path.

can anyone suggest me how I could do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just create a global function `updateToGivenFile` (or whatever) that takes a file name as a parameter, and call that function from `NodeList::updateToFile` and `InventoryList::updateToFile`.

There's no particular need to do this by derivation from a base class but I don't see the problem if you want to do it that way either.

Answer (score 1):

C++ as the concept of free functions. So in most cases, you don't want to use inheritance but create free functions.

And your `updateToFile` definitely a candidate for a beeing a free function:

```cpp
void write_to_file(NodeList* pNodeList)
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(pNodeList->writeTImer.GetEnabled() && pNodeList->writeTImer.IsDone())
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> panellock(pNodeList->mutex_NodeInvConf);
//#if _DEBUG_LOG
            FILE * pFile;
            std::string conff =  pNodeList->NodeInvConfiguration.toStyledString();
            pFile = fopen (KV_FOLDER_LOCATION DIR_SEP KV_READABLE_NODELIST_FILE , "wb");
            fwrite (conff.c_str() , sizeof(char), conff.length(), pFile);
            fclose (pFile);
            sync();
//#endif
            FILE * pFile2;
            pFile2 = fopen (/*KV_FOLDER_LOCATION DIR_SEP KV_NODELIST_FILE*/SYS_PNL_PATH, "wb");
            PrintJSONTree(pNodeList->NodeInvConfiguration,0,pFile2);
            fclose (pFile2);
            sync();
            pNodeList->writeTImer.SetEnabled(false);
            LOG_G("Nodelist file updated");
            LOGS_INFO("Nodelist file updated");
            MessageQueInterface::getInstance()->sendInventory(false);

        }
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

And then use that in your member function:

```cpp
void NodeList::updateToFile()
{
   write_to_file(pNodeList)
}
```

Or don't use a member function at all.

If you take a look at the classes in the STD you can see that they limit inheritance and member function to the absolute minimum, and use free functions when ever possible.

Comment: I didn't get anything??

Comment: @Sachin you should be more precise about what you don't understand.

Comment: This is fine for NodeList.cpp. what about InventoryList.cpp?? should i write one more write_to_file there??

Comment: @Sachin no, place the `write_to_file` in an own .cpp file, and add its declaration to an .h file which you include in both `NodeList.cpp` and `InventoryList.cpp`. Or add the definition of `write_to_file` to the .h  file and make it `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly simple. Create a base class:

```
class BaseList
{
public:
  BaseList(const std::string& path)
  : path( path ), thread(&BaseList::updateToFile, this)
  {
  }

private:
  std::string path;
  std::thread thread;

  void updateToFile();
};
```

Note that I've replaced your `pthread` usage with `std::thread` which makes your code portable and simpler.

You can then create sub classes:

```
class NodeList : public BaseList
{
public:
  static NodeList& getInstance()
  {
    static NodeList instance;
    return instance;
  }
private:
  NodeList()
  : BaseList("Nodes path")
  {}
};

class InventoryList: public BaseList
{
public:
  static InventoryList& getInstance()
  {
    static InventoryListinstance;
    return instance;
  }
private:
  InventoryList()
  : BaseList("Inventory path")
  {}
};
```

Here I've replaced your `std::call_once` with the simpler function statics to create your instances.

Comment: can you please explain how i could implement that for my problem here

Comment: where should i add my void updatetofile function  then??

Comment: how do i call that updateToFile() in derived classes then??

Comment: you don't need to, its called by the thread the same as in your example. If you need to call it explicitly then make it protected or public rather than private